# AWS Organizations service for creating SAAS app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, saas

I'm thinking of using [AWS Organizations service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_introduction.html) to manage a SAAS app.

So, for every user registered in this potential startup I intend to create an account in my AWS Organization so I can track how much I need to charge each account.

For the record, The application consists of a few AWS lamda functions and a dynamoDB database.

Considering there is a limit on a number of accounts in an organization, I just wanted to know is AWS Organizations service a good fit for my use-case? The problem is that at the moment, I don't know how many accounts I would need.

If it's not a good fit, is there any alternative you would recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, creating separate accounts for lots of users / departments (more than say a dozen) is not good practice for budgeting and cost control.

Instead Amazon recommends using Cost Allocation Tags. You will have much better fine grained control over where your costs are.

Note: I do recommend using multiple accounts such as production, development, etc. This is more of a security / separation of responsibility than cost control.

Here is a link to help see if this will fit your objectives:

[Using Cost Allocation Tags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html)

> **Using Cost Allocation Tags**
>
> A tag is a label that you or AWS assigns to an AWS resource. Each tag
>   consists of a key and a value. A key can have more than one value. You
>   can use tags to organize your resources, and cost allocation tags to
>   track your AWS costs on a detailed level. After you activate cost
>   allocation tags, AWS uses the cost allocation tags to organize your
>   resource costs on your cost allocation report, to make it easier for
>   you to categorize and track your AWS costs. AWS provides two types of
>   cost allocation tags, an AWS-generated tag and user-defined tags. AWS
>   defines, creates, and applies the AWS-generated tag for you, and you
>   define, create, and apply user-defined tags. You must activate both
>   types of tags separately before they can appear in Cost Explorer or on
>   a cost allocation report.